# Is there any way to get current timestamp in Date format

Tags: scala

Is there any way to get current timestamp in Date format in scala. I needed to create a date histogram and new Date() gives time in seconds and not in dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm format

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the classes from the `java.time` package:

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format._

val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime.now().format(format)
```

Comment: also you can set time-zone if you needed

Comment: But then you better use OffsetDateTime